# Notifications with Amazon SES, through Amazon SNS

Tags: php, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

My goal is quit simple, I want to configure amazon SNS to receive my amazon SES emails notifications (Bounces, Complaints, Deliveries).

So I make the configuration as the doc:

```
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/configure-sns-notifications.html
```

Into Amazon SES > Domains > Notifications > Edit Configuration
I created a new SES topic and select it in SNS topic configuration for Bounces, Complaints and Deliveries.

In Amazon SNS, I selected my topic > Actions > Subscribe to topic and put my PHP script url in the Endpoint input.

My php script is basic, just to see if it's working:

```
$postBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
$requete = "INSERT INTO amazon(json) VALUES('$postBody')";
$db->exec($requete);
```

But my script seems to never be called... However I am sending emails with Amazon SES right now.

What's wrong in my configuration ? Did I missed somethink ?

Amazon said: "A confirmation message will be sent to the subscribed endpoint. Once the subscription has been confirmed, the endpoint will receive notifications from this topic."
But nothing never append... :(

Thanks for help

Comment: Is the server rubbing this script accessible from the Internet?  Access allowed from 0.0.0.0/0 to port 80 OR 443 in the security group, etc.?

Comment: First check if your endpoint is publicly accessible over the internet. Try calling it from POSTMAN with some sample payload.